# Filtering out array items in a CosmosDB query with best performance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In CosmosDB I am able to select documents where items in an array have a given value using ARRAY_CONTAINS. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM d WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(d.Assignments, {'Owner':'Jason'}, true)
```

In the above query I get the following returned:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Apple",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Orange",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Pear",
                "Owner": "Amy"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Pear",
                "Owner": "Liz"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Liz"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However I would also like the returned JSON to have all array items that do not match my query to be filtered out. For example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Apple",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Orange",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would prefer to find a way to do this in my query assuming I can do so with good performance and relatively low Request Units.

Is it more advisable to filter out the results in code once the JSON is returned?

In some scenarios I may have a few hundred array items with about 60-80% needing to be filtered out.

Comment: a) I don't know much about CosmosDB but how come in the first example `{'Owner':'Jason'}` doesn't seem to be doing the filtering in the first place? b) _"Is it more advisable to filter out the results in code once the JSON is returned?"_ - would be better if the DB does the filtering

Comment: a) I'm asking Cosmos for records that have arrays with that name/key value. It does not assume that I don't want the to see the rest of the items in that array. In other words I've filtered out the root documents that don't have array elements with that match. b) Most likely yes, but Cosmos also has Request Unit (RU) restrictions that effect price/performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added 3 more similar documents for these records. You can use below query to fulfill this requirement in an optimum way:

```
SELECT f.id, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM c in f.Assignments WHERE c.Owner = 'Jason') AS Assignments FROM f WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(f.Assignments, {'Owner':'Jason'}, true)
```

**Results:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Apple",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            },
            {
                "Fruit": "Orange",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "Assignments": [
            {
                "Fruit": "Grape",
                "Owner": "Jason"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Query Stats:**

[image]

Comment: But if there is a document that does not have an Assignment to 'Jason' in your query it is returned as a result. This query should only return documents that have 'Jason' as an 'Owner' and then remove all other associations. For example if there are 100 documents and Jason is in 20 of them your query returns all 100 documents. My original filters down to the 20 relevant documents first.

Comment: I made your query work by adding my query after 'From f': SELECT f.id, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM c in f.Assignments WHERE c.Owner = 'Jason') AS Assignments
FROM f  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(f.Assignments, {'Owner':'Jason'}, true) - If you can update I will mark as answer!

Comment: Hey, check the updated query. It will return the result as you want.

Comment: Can you update the formatting before I mark it. Looks like the added code is not in the code block. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Thank you. Just a note that when I used this in my .NET Core app using the 3.0 SDK I was getting an error on "Select * FROM c" and had to change it to "Select c.Fruit, c.Owner from c". The error I got when not selecting specific properties was: "'SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set."